# Android: footer not visible with RelativeLayout in android 2.3

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-relativelayout

In an android layout xml file, I'm using a RelativeLayout, which contains a footer and also a ScrollView.

I want the footer to be always visible.
In Android 4.0 it works fine.
However on a device which is running android 2.3 the footer is not visible at all. 
The scrollview seems to push it out of visible region.

How can I ensure that even on devices using older versions of android that the footer is always visible?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android         = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools           = "http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width  = "match_parent"
                android:layout_height = "match_parent" >

  <!-- Footer content  -->
  <LinearLayout
        android:id                       = "@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width             = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height            = "wrap_content"
        android:background               = "@color/black" 
    android:layout_alignParentEnd    = "true" >

  <!-- Footer content -->
  </LinearLayout>

  <ScrollView
     android:layout_width      = "fill_parent"
     android:layout_height     = "wrap_content"
     android:fillViewport      = "true"
     android:layout_above      = "@id/footer"
     android:background        = "@drawable/background_pattern" >

  etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to define your scroll view before your footer or to use [android:layout_alignParentBottom](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_alignParentBottom) instead of [android:layout_alignParentEnd](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_alignParentEnd). Your other layouts can be so big so "parent end" may be outside your screen bounds

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.
I tried that but it didn't work.
The footer was still not visible.

Comment: Try to use android:layout_alignParentBottom instead of android:layout_alignParentEnd

Comment: Actually, I've solved it now.
The problem was caused by a silly bug in my code.